# Escape sequence cannot be gotten in if-else statement

Tags: python, django

Escape sequence cannot be gotten in if-else statement.I wrote codes,

```
 import re
    def get_id(request):
        id= "100¥a"
        if re.search(r"[\0-\037]", id):
            return HttpResponse('<h1>Escape sequence</h1>')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('<h1>OK</h1>')
```

In this case,I think program go into `if re.search(r"[\0-\037]", id):` ,but always  it go into else statement.I really cannot understand why.Is the way of getting escape sequence in if statement wrong?How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
import re
  def get_id(request):
    id= "100¥a"
    pattern = re.compile(r'[\\u000-\\u037]', re.UNICODE | re.IGNORECASE)
    if pattern.findall(id):
      return HttpResponse('<h1>Escape sequence</h1>')
    else:
      return HttpResponse('<h1>OK</h1>')
```

You can extract the pattern compilation to happen once inside your module, so it doesn't need to be done at the handling of each request, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: thx,ur code works for me!!But I cannot understand why I cannot catch escape sequence by using before my code.Why is it?

Comment: @user8817477 I think you could even just use `re.match('[\u0000-\u0037]', id)`.  I believe the biggest issue is that you need 4 digits for your unicode representation.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is that you try to identify if there is any special character [0-31] or [128-inf] in a string, by using python.

This is the correct code:

```
id= "100¥a"
if re.search(r"[\u0000-\u001F]|[\u0080-\uFFFF]", id):
    print("Special character")
else:
    print("No special character")
```

Your case is valid only for octal codes under space character but your yen character is above 80.

Comment: I rewrote  re.search(r"[\x00-\x1F\x7F]", inp_id) ,but same thing happens...How should I fix this?

Comment: Use my code. \x00  handles only 8 bytes, while \U handles 16 bit chars. The way you wrote the regex means it matches zero to 1F or the \x7F character.

Comment: Also, the code from Matt Morgan works because it matches "1" not the yen sign. 37 in hex is the number '7', so both '0' and '1' are matches for his regex, but not the yen sign.